# nginx ipv6 SSL server block responding to basic http port 80 connections

Tags: nginx, ssl

Running into an issue that I haven't seen before.

In my nginx config, I have a server block setup for a single subdomain that is only listening on port 443 (ssl).

However, when I test the connection out using port 80, its still responding. Very head scratching at the moment.

For example, `curl http://blog.omgtrolls.com` should not be able to connect, yet it does and spits out the site html etc. Running with verbose mode `curl -v` shows that it indeed is completing the connection on 80.

```
curl -v http://blog.omgtrolls.com
*   Trying 2607:f8b0:4005:814::200e...
* Connected to blog.omgtrolls.com (2607:f8b0:4005:814::200e) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: blog.omgtrolls.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
< Date: Fri, 28 Apr 2023 01:02:17 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;
< 
* Connection #0 to host blog.omgtrolls.com left intact
<html>blah blah</html>
```

`curl https://blog.omgtrolls.com` of course works as expected.

Here's a simplified version of my setup:

I recently added a new `_default.nginx` config to my standard setup. (I have a single config repo that gets deployed to a couple of different servers. `_default.nginx` gets deployed to all of them. This config is meant to prevent domains pointing to the same server IP from being served other hosted sites.

I'm thinking perhaps that this *may* be related to this new problem.

```
# _default.nginx
# default server config to prevent undefined domains from returning responses.
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  return 404;
}
```

Next, I have a different nginx config file for the subddomain in question. Here's the simple version (domains changed to protect the innocent):

```
# omgtrolls.nginx
upstream nodejs_upstream{
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
  server_name blog.omgtrolls.com;

  listen [::]:443 ssl;

  root /usr/local/apps/omgtrolls/;

  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;" always;

  # required for LetsEncrypt
  location ~ /.well-known {
    allow all;
  }

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/omgtrolls.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/omgtrolls.com/privkey.pem;

  location / {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_cache off;
    proxy_cache_key sfs$request_uri$scheme;
    proxy_pass http://nodejs_upstream;
  }
}
```

Notice that I *don't* have a server block to catch port 80 requests and upgrade them to 443. I specifically have that bit disabled right now once I noticed this issue.

What *should* be happening is that I can only connect on https/443 and otherwise the connection should fail.

Is there something with my `_default.nginx` setup that is causing this?